# Motorcycle chewing through too many front tyres

Tags: motorcycle, tires, suspension, triumph

I have a Y2K Triumph Speed Triple that has an excessive appetite for front tyres. It eats two front tyres for each rear tyre. This is the reverse of what it should be. I run the tyres at about 38 PSI and mainly do city commuting - no racing here, no stoppies or even hard riding. The suspension is set up very hard though, I'm not sure if this will have an impact. I use sports-touring tyres.

Any ideas on why my front tyre wears out quicker than my rear?

Comment: Its Normal, The front always wears faster if your primary commute is city drive. (since you will break a LOT)

Answer (score 6):

It might be worth checking to see if the wear pattern looks odd at all. I've heard that if you're wheel is out of alignment or unbalanced it can cause excessive and distinctive tyre wear. See this page for a fairly comprehensive treatment of tyre wear: http://www.rattlebars.com/tirewear/index.html

Having your suspension set up very hard can make you go through front tyres faster, so will doing a lot a heavy breaking, especially if you only use your front brake for slowing. Using a balanced combination of both brakes can help spread the tyre wear between the two tyres, although you would always expect a little more brake force at the front and therefore a little more wear.

Comment: There was no obvious issues with the tyre aside from cupping. As regards braking, the speed triple has front brakes that can stop a planet but rear brakes that couldn't slow a butterfly. This is the curse of sports bikes I suppose. I reckon I'll soften the front suspension and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Frequently, a motorcyclist will adjust his/her front forks up or down in the triple clamps to change trail and rake on the bike.

Changing trail and rake on a motorcycle can effect the handling of the vehicle and change the weight distribution under cornering and braking.

Increasing the rake makes the bike more stable at higher speeds and decreases responsiveness of turning input at the handlebar.

Decreasing the rake makes the bike more prone to speed wobbles (at the extreme) and sharpens turning input responsiveness.

By raising the forks in a set of triple clamps there will be more weight distributed to a motorcycles front wheel.  Where additional wear can come into play is corning with the added weight.  This makes the turning much sharper and requires less energy/input to perform the turn.  This will wear out a tire much quicker than an opposite fork tube/triple clamp placement configuration.

**Image of forks raised in triple clamps**

[image]

***If you have done this, raised your forks in the triple clamps, then this can account for a higher rate of wear on your front tire.***

My own wear per tire looks like two rear tires for every one front.  I ride my bike pretty hard and trail brake into corners VERY hard when I'm out having fun.  I'm punish my ride and wring every last penny of fun I can out of it.  (mind you I am very conservative on city streets) So I feel like I torture my tires as good as the next guy.  Also, I don't do silly things like break stands or rip wheelies all the time to account for increased rear tire wear.